# Proving the equivalence of $P_1{\implies}Q_1$ and $P_2{\implies}Q_2$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need to show that these two theorems are equivalent:

Theorem 1: if $P_1$, then $Q_1$
Theorem 2: if $P_2$, then $Q_2$

Does that mean that I need to show the following?

Assume that Theorem 1 is true and $P_2$ is true, need to show $Q_2$ is true.
Assume that Theorem 2 is true and $P_1$ is true, need to show $Q_1$ is true.

Also, if $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are the same statement, if I need to show that Theorem 1 and Theorem 2 are equivalent, is that the same as showing that $P_1 {\iff} P_2$?

Comment: "Does that mean that I need to show the following? Assume... , show Q2... Assume..., show Q1... ." Yes that will prove equivalence of the two theorems. If Q1 is Q2, you'll probably end up proving that $P_1 \iff P_2$ but *they* are not necessarily equivalent, and without knowing more about these statements it's not possible to say more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T_1 := P_1 \implies Q_1$ and $T_2 := P_2 \implies Q_2$

You are trying to prove

$$T_1 \iff T_2$$

[Wikipedia's article on **Logical Equivalence**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence#Logical_equivalences_involving_biconditionals) offers various strategies for proving $T_1 \iff T_2$.

For example,

> $p \iff q \equiv p \implies q \land q \implies p$

which in your case is saying that you can prove

$$T_1 \iff T_2$$

by proving both

$$
\begin{aligned}
T_1 &\implies T_2 &&(1)\\
T_2 &\implies T_1 &&(2)\\
\end{aligned}
$$

So, for example, you would need to prove $(1)$. Either $T_1$ is true or it's false.

If $T_1$ is false, then $(1)$ is vacuously true.

If $T_1$ is true, then you need to prove $T_2$.
So assume $T_1 = P_1 \implies Q_1$ is true.

In $T_2$, if $P_2$ is false, then $T_2$ is vacuously true; if $P_2$ is true, then you need to prove $Q_2$.

So, yes

> Assume Theorem $1$ is true and $P_1$ is true, need to show $Q_2$ is true.
>
> Assume Theorem $2$ is true and $P_1$ is true, need to show $Q_2$ is true.

summarize what you need to do prove $(1)$ and $(2)$, respectively.

---

> Also, if $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are the same statement, if I need to show Theorem $1$ and Theorem $2$ are equivalent, is that the same as showing $P_1 \iff P_2$

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

> Theorem 1: if $A$, then $R$
>  Theorem 2: if $B$, then $S$
>
> Does showing the following prove that Theorem 1$\iff$Theorem 2?
>
> Assume that Theorem 1 and $B$ are true, then show that $S$ is
> true.
>  Assume that Theorem 2 and $A$ are true, then show that $R$ is true.

Yes, this works:

[image]

---

> Theorem 3: if $A$, then $Q$
>  Theorem 4: if $B$, then $Q$
>
> Is proving that $A{ \iff }B$ the same as proving that Theorem 3$\iff$Theorem 4?

Not without further information:

[image: ![enter image description here]

For example, if $A$ and $Q$ both stand for `1+1=2` and $B$ stands for `1+1=3`, then Theorem 3 is equivalent to Theorem 4 even though $A$ is inequivalent to $B.$

However, proving that $A{\iff}B$ is *sufficient* to prove that Theorem 3$\iff$Theorem 4:

[image]